# Getting no user exists when retrieving my own recent media

Tags: python, python-2.7, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to get the info from my last posted photo on Instagram using the API wrapper for Python found [here.](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram)

It's based off this usage:

```
api.user_recent_media(user_id, count, max_id)
```

So I did this:

```
last_post = api.user_recent_media(user_id,1,1)
print last_post
```

And I get:

```
Followers: 7 (+0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_ig_follower_count.py", line 52, in <module>
    last_post = api.user_recent_media(user_id,2,3)
  File "B:\MegaSync\Programming\Python\AonnixPromo\lib\site-packages\instagram\b
ind.py", line 197, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "B:\MegaSync\Programming\Python\AonnixPromo\lib\site-packages\instagram\b
ind.py", line 189, in execute
    content, next = self._do_api_request(url, method, body, headers)
  File "B:\MegaSync\Programming\Python\AonnixPromo\lib\site-packages\instagram\b
ind.py", line 163, in _do_api_request
    raise InstagramAPIError(status_code, content_obj['meta']['error_type'], cont
ent_obj['meta']['error_message'])
instagram.bind.InstagramAPIError: (400) APINotFoundError-this user does not exis
t
```

As you  can see at the top, my api and user_id work fine, because they successfully retrieving my follower count.

The account is also the admin of the sandbox.

Comment: I already checked that, but here it is: 1828689610

Comment: are u in sandbox mode?

Answer (score 0):

You are in Sandbox mode, so you have to add the user you want to access via API to sandbox authorized list.

`Go to instagram.com/developer > Manage Client > Edit > Sandbox tab > type username and Enter > click "Save Changes"`

If you access a user that is not in sandbox user list, it will return error message: "this user does not exist"

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"APINotFoundError","code":400,"error_message":"this user does not exist"}}
```

Comment: It says "Cannot invite aonnix. The admin is always a sandbox user."